# Use a FOR loop to return SelectedValue of DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been spending a lot of time searching for a solution to what seems to be a simple thing.

The following returns the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error. I put this code on a separate blank page for troubleshooting. Any ideas?

ASP.Net:

```
<div>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ChoosePattern1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CssClass="dropformat"
        AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="getimage">
        <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ChoosePattern2" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CssClass="dropformat"
        AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="getimage">
        <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

C# Codebehind:

```
protected void getimage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int intCounter = 1; intCounter <= 8; intCounter++)
    {
        string mypattern = "ChoosePattern" + Convert.ToString(intCounter);

        DropDownList ddl = Page.FindControl(mypattern) as DropDownList;
        Response.Write(ddl.SelectedValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Object reference not set...` means that you are accessing a variable, or a property, that is `null`. Which variable or property is null? Use the development tools available to you to check this. If this is your exact ASPX and your exact codebehind C# code, it probably faults when `intCounter == 3`.

Comment: Something else to check, from the docs: The `FindControl1 method searches only the page's immediate, or top-level, container; it does not recursively search for controls in naming containers contained on the page.

Comment: Indeed - I forgot to change the array from 8 to 2, and this works. I suspect that maybe it doesn't work in my project as I'm using Master pages... and yes will have to search recursively. I have seen examples posted, but am having a hard time understanding how to use them.

Comment: Please don't edit your post to include the corrected code once you find the answer--it renders your question obsolete for anyone that finds it in the future.

Comment: Will do eddie_cat - edited back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error message is what is called a "Null Reference Exception". It usually means you're trying to access a property from an object, but that object is null.

In your case, `ddl` is probably the problem. If it's not found by `Page.FindControl` (or if the returned object is not a `DropDownList`), the value stored will be null. Therefore, accessing the `SelectedValue` will cause the exception.

Comment: Yes - I just realized that - Edited, and this works! I just built a two dropdown example - my project has 8 and I cut/pasted, forgot to change the example.

Answer (score 0):

You are requesting ChoosePattern1...ChoosePattern8 items, but on page only ChoosePattern1 and ChoosePattern2 exist. So for

```
DropDownList ddl = Page.FindControl("ChoosePattern3") as DropDownList;
```

you get null, because drop down with such ID doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Change

for (int intCounter = 1; intCounter <= 8; intCounter++)

to

for (int intCounter = 1; intCounter <= 2; intCounter++)